# Google AMP URL for dynamic pages

Tags: amp-html

I have aspx files that will read the contents from the database and I need to incorporate AMP in the aspx files. How do I incorporate into the link url() in my aspx file? I have written a tempAMP.aspx file to do the conversion.I am using a query string to pass from my aspx file to the tempAMP.aspx to retrieve the content from the database. Is Google able to search for my AMP page even with the query string?
Appreciate if anyone can help.

### ASPX File

```
<link rel="amphtml" href=""http://tempAMP.aspx?IND=1">
```

IND is a key that I will use to retrieve from the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use a query parameter and still the page be cacheable.
For example, The Independent does something similar, if you go to the [canonical page](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/labour-poll-wales-general-election-2017-16-point-shift-swing-a7749786.html) and then look for `amphtml`, you will find:

```
<link href="http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/politics/labour-poll-wales-general-election-2017-16-point-shift-swing-a7749786.html?amp" rel="amphtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to count as an AMP page (on top of being an actual AMP document) a page needs to include a `link` element with the `rel` of `amphtml` and a valid `href`. The documentation says nothing about disallowing query strings so I would assume your URL is perfectly valid.

Keep in mind that you should have this kind of links pointing both ways if you want to pair up your AMP and non-AMP pages.

To quote [the documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/prepare_for_discovery):

> In order to establish that a non-AMP page and an AMP page should be treated as being "paired" together, we add information about the AMP page to the non-AMP page and vice versa, in the form of  tags in the .
>
> Add the following to the non-AMP page:
>
> ```
> <link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
> ```
>
> And this to the AMP page
>
> ```
> <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
> ```

That said, Google is able to find AMP pages even if they have no non-AMP equivalents. As long as there are links leading to your page, it will be indexed. You only need a `canonical` link if a non-AMP version doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi toniedzwiedz,

For example, will this work if my non-AMP page has the code "<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/ampPage.aspx?ID=14566">"
where 14566 is encrypted ID and my AMP page has this code "<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/NormalPage.aspx">? My page is able to link back and fro in my development mode if I use the AMP View extension in Chrome to test it out. Is Google side able to cache and know which page to link back?

Comment: @snowfrost when it comes to caching on Google's CDN, I'm afraid I don't know. I think it would be best to ask Google. If you're worried about query parameters affecting caches, it should be easy enough transform your code to read the ID from a path segment in the URL.

Comment: I have a non-html page : [link] (https://www.youth.sg/Users/S/H/ShermanWong/2017/5/Creating-art-for-Charlie-Lim) and when I use the AMP extension installed in my Chrome to verify the AMP page [link](https://www.youth.sg/sublayouts/YouthSG/Article/ArticleAMPPage.aspx?item=2696c638-2290-4826-aaae-17047a84fb95)  , it give me no error. However, when I test in [link](https://search.google.com/search-console/amp)  ,it state that is not a valid AMP page. Anyone can help?